# How to tell Visual Studio not to display the same warning multiple times?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, settings, warnings, error-list

A few weeks ago I started noticing that my VS displays some warnings twice. Same Line/Column for both displayed warnings. It's exactly the same warning which is displayed twice within the Error List.

For example:

I've added the following line within my code such that I don't forget it because the whole solution has quite a few TODO marks:

```
#warning TODO: Refactoring needed
```

When I hit "Rebuild solution" VS ends up displaying the same warning twice. Once as warning 1 and again as number 10.

I've tried reverting VS settings to default and I've also reinstalled VS. Still the warning is displayed twice.

I haven't found any solution yet and I thought maybe I ask if someone has seen this problem before. Maybe someone can tell me how to resolve this problem since it start to really upset me.

Comment: The warning message might be appropriate.  Sounds like you use the source code file in more than one project.  Look at the Output window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is being compiled more than once. Each pass is going to produce that warning, just as each pass produces some code. Check that you don't actually have multiple files with the same name or the same file referenced via link in another project.